How do I get interface similar to moto G first generation, android 7.1.1 or iphone 6 in galaxy S22?
I want the homescreen/layout of my samsung S22 to be similar to the earlier moto G phone or android 7.1.1 where you have apps on particular screens and doesn't have the new things that popup if you swipe past the right most screen or in a particular way.
Like hide those apps and widgets away a bit.
So I guess I'm looking for an app launcher preferably free or less than $10.
Also posted on Android.SE: android.stackexchange.com/q/258638/44325  was told to post here.

You should edit your post and add the detail that you are looking for an app launcher that uses this layout/behavior. And you should add what type of app you are searching, free, open source or paid and if the latter how much are you willing to pay.

Also posted on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/258638/44325
